# vbscript skip folders that will throw Permission Denied Error in recursive call

Tags: vbscript

I am looping thru all folders on my C: drive in windows 7. I am using vbscript. How can I detect if a permission denied error will occur on a folder so that I can skip that folder and keep processing the rest of the folders.

```
Sub SearchForWsFiles(strFolderPath)

    Dim objFolder
    Dim objFile
    Dim objSubFolder

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    objLogFile.WriteLine(objFolder.Name)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "ws") Then
            objLogFile.WriteLine(objFile.Name)
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call SearchForWsFiles(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a strictly local "On Error Resume Next" to test whether you can access the folder-to be-processed's .Files.Count/.SubFolders.Count. If not, don't recurse.

Comment: I'd upvote this if you had provided examples - the code above is short - why not provide a corrected example - where to put EXACTLY how you would test?